# Starting a process in VBS: path not found

Tags: vbscript

I need to make a simple vbs script to run some process' automatically. I found the following script on microsoft's website. It works fine to run notepad.exe the way the original example shows, but I'm trying to modify it to run myprog.exe. The full path to this program is: `C:\myprogdir\myprog.exe`

```
Const SW_NORMAL = 1
strComputer = "."
strCommand = "myprog.exe" 
strPath = "C:\myprogdir\"

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" _
    & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

' Configure the Notepad process to show a window
Set objStartup = objWMIService.Get("Win32_ProcessStartup")
Set objConfig = objStartup.SpawnInstance_
objConfig.ShowWindow = SW_NORMAL

' Create Notepad process
Set objProcess = objWMIService.Get("Win32_Process")
intReturn = objProcess.Create _
    (strCommand, strPath, objConfig, intProcessID)
If intReturn <> 0 Then
    Wscript.Echo "Process could not be created." & _
        vbNewLine & "Command line: " & strCommand & _
        vbNewLine & "Return value: " & intReturn
Else
    Wscript.Echo "Process created." & _
        vbNewLine & "Command line: " & strCommand & _
        vbNewLine & "Process ID: " & intProcessID
End If
```

I keep getting Return value: 9, which indicates "Path Not Found". However the path is correct. Is there something I'm not getting?

Comment: At 1st sight, I think the configuration is not right.

Comment: @DavidCandy: A simpler one-liner: `CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "C:\myprogdir\myprog.exe"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need all that to start a process, you just need the Shell object. Also, be sure to wrap the path of your executable in quotes (in case the path has spaces). Like this:

```
Option Explicit

Dim shl

Set shl = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Call shl.Run("""C:\myprogdir\myprog.exe""")
Set shl = Nothing

WScript.Quit
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless the path to your program is included in the system's `%PATH%` environment variable you need to specify the commandline with the full path to the executable. Specifying the path just as the working directory will not work.

```
strProgram = "myprog.exe" 
strPath    = "C:\myprogdir"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strCommand = fso.BuildPath(strPath, strProgram)

...

intReturn = objProcess.Create(strCommand, strPath, objConfig, intProcessID)
```

Using the `BuildPath` method will save you the headaches caused by having to keep track of leading/trailing backslashes.

Note that you need to put double quotes around a path that contains spaces, e.g. like this:

```
strCommand = Chr(34) & fso.BuildPath(strPath, strProgram) & Chr(34)
```

As others have already pointed out, there are simpler ways to start a process on the local computer, like [`Run`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28v=vs.84%29.aspx):

```
Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
sh.Run strCommand, 1, True
```

or [`ShellExecute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg537745%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
Set app = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
app.ShellExecute strCommand, , strPath, , 1
```

There are some notable differences between `Run` and `ShellExecute`, though. The former can be run either synchronously or asynchronously (which means the command either does or doesn't wait for the external program to terminate). The latter OTOH always runs asynchronously (i.e. the method returns immediately without waiting for the external program to terminate), but has the advantage that it can be used to launch programs with elevated privileges when UAC is enabled by specifying the verb `"runas"` as the 4<sup>th</sup> argument.

However, these methods only allow for launching processes on the local computer. If you want to be able to launch processes on remote computers you will have to use WMI:

```
strComputer = "otherhost"

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" _
  & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389290%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more information about WMI connections to remote hosts.